# Uploading files in google colab

Tags: java, google-colaboratory

So I am writing code in java in google colab because I want to copy-paste the code in android studio to perform a specific function. Now in python it is pretty easy to upload files to google colab but I want to do it in java (I particularly want to upload image files). I should be able to upload image files in such a way that I can use it as input in my code. How can I do it? Also, for all the packages that I import in google colab, will I have to separately download them for android studio or can I just copy-paste the code and it will run?

Answer (score 0):

Google Colab presents a Jupyter-notebook like environment for Python code only. It cannot run Java code (at least, I cannot find where you'd make it do that).

> I want to copy-paste the code in android studio to perform a specific function

Android code runs on an Android device, not in a server.

If you want to run Java code on a server, then you'd host an HTTP-based Java web-server that you use an HTTP Client from Android app to communicate with it. (In theory, yes, you can install and run JAR files in Colab, but you would then need to know the IP of those servers in order to connect with them).

The more appropriate solution would be to use Google AppEngine or GCE/GKE (assuming you want to use Google Cloud)

> I ... want to upload image files

You can use the [Java Google Drive SDK](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/java) for that

> for all the packages that I import in google colab, will I have to separately download them for android studio

Android Studio is an IDE. Gradle will download packages for compiling your Java/Android code, yes, but as mentioned, Colab is downloading Python packages, not Java

Comment: I have downloaded IJava from github and am successfully running java code in google colab. Is it possible to write a short code snippet for how I can upload image files using java google drive sdk?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads

Comment: Regardless, you can use Android Studio to make a plain runnable Java application. Why use Colab?

Comment: Is there a way to just write a code in Python in google colab and then add that into android studio? Something just like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69745839/16571762)? Java is truly causing unnecessary complications

Comment: As answered, you'd need to run a web-server in Colab (Python Flask, for example). Then you need to expose Colab to the open internet (bypassing Google Cloud, using ngrok, for example). Then you need to use an HTTP Client from Android to send input data and parse a response. **But** Colab is not meant to run for a long period of time and the IP address is not consistent. This is why using other cloud-hosted solutions that you can control is recommended

Comment: Hi, can you suggest what interface to use instead of Google Colab which will be easiest to import into Android Studio?