# Adding an ML model into Android Studio

Tags: android, google-colaboratory

I have written an ML model using Keras in Google Colab which detects whether an animal is a cat or a dog based on an input image.

Now, I want to create an app in Android Studio that takes an image as input, uses the algorithm I have designed to detect whether the image is a cat or a dog and outputs the result.

My question is how can I incorporate this algorithm into Android Studio? My first thought was to rewrite the code in Java and copy it into Android Studio but writing Java in Google Colab would lead to multiple complications. Hence, is there a way to download the algorithm I have created and upload it into Android Studio such that it works? If not, what other approach can I implement?

My desired outcome is something where I can add the algorithm into Android Studio and write a code like:

```
if (algorithm == true)
    //output dog detected
else
    //output cat detected
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Studio is just an IDE. It doesn't run the actual code. And no, it doesn't run Python.

You should be able to export the Keras model into a offline format that Android can use via Tensorflow; [Keras deep learning model to android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45874245/keras-deep-learning-model-to-android)

Alternatively, to deploy an "online model", you'd run a hosted web-server that exposed the model over HTTP, which your Android code would send in requests to and parse the response.

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain the difference between an "online" and "offline" format?

Comment: As answered, online means access to the internet, and can also be modified over time without re-deploying the client. Offline models are exported functions that would require pushing updates to the app in order to be changed. Offline models also take up storage space on each client device

Comment: Okay, thank you! My model does not need access to the internet. So I don't need to do any web-server connections and so on... Also, using Python in Google Colab is fine right? (Sorry but I'm quite inexperienced with all this so please forgive my "stupid" questions)

Comment: I never said you couldn't use Python in Colab. I was saying that "copying Python code to Android from Colab" isn't really possible.

Comment: I meant to ask whether it's fine to use Python instead of Java in Google Colab and then export the Keras model because Python is not compatible with Android Studio.

Comment: I don't really have experience with Keras or Java on Colab, but using Python/Jupyter is what Colab is meant for, yes.

Comment: So if I use Python there won't be any compatibility problems when importing into Android Studio right?

Comment: There might be compatibility problems between various versions of Keras and Tensorflow models, but I haven't used either.

Comment: That's fine, I just wanted to make sure Android Studio won't have problems after the Tenserflow model (in Python) is ready.